# Logitech mx master 2 not detected

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech, detect

I have a dual-boot system (Windows 10/Ubuntu). Recently I bought an MX Master 2 Bluetooth mouse. I tend to use it without a receiver. Now in Windows 10, I can pair it and it works perfectly but, Ubuntu doesn't even detect the mouse. However, Ubuntu detects and successfully pairs other devices, like my Bluetooth earbuds and Bluetooth speaker. Any ideas What the problem might be?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? My MX Ergo and MX Master 2 both work fine in 18.04, but it seems impossible to pair them to 16.04 on a PC.

Comment: I tried every version. And other distros as well. Also I noticed when on WiFi and connected to Bluetooth speaker YouTube videos loads very slow, stucks every 2 seconds and switches to the lowest resolution automatically. Tried with different wifi's and different channels. Mayit's an hardware issue?

Comment: It's possible. Could you please [edit] your question and include specific model information for your bluetooth/wifi module?